# Create trigger and stored procedure that updates Datetime when user is authenticated

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I created a Login System in PHP and MySQL and I have the following table for the users:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Authenticated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `Surname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `Username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `Email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Password` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
    `Created_At` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    `Authenticated_At` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When the user signs up, a user is inserted in the table users with `Authenticated = 0`. I, as the admin, have to authenticate the user using:

```
UPDATE users SET Authenticated = 1 WHERE ID = {$id};
```

What I'd like to know is how to create a trigger and a stored procedure that updates the `Authenticated_At` column to the current Date and Time after the aforementioned `UPDATE` query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `UPDATE users SET Authenticated = 1 WHERE ID = {$id};` looks prone to SQL injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The simplest possible solution :

```
UPDATE users SET Authenticated = 1, Authenticated_At = NOW() WHERE ID = {$id};
```

2) Another solution is to set a `DEFAULT` value for the timestamp value. This is implemented in the table definition, like :

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Authenticated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `Surname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `Username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `Email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Password` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
    `Created_At` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    `Authenticated_At` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

From  [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) :

> An auto-updated column is automatically updated to the current timestamp when the value of any other column in the row is changed from its current value. An auto-updated column remains unchanged if all other columns are set to their current values. To prevent an auto-updated column from updating when other columns change, explicitly set it to its current value. To update an auto-updated column even when other columns do not change, explicitly set it to the value it should have (for example, set it to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

In order for the `Authenticated_At` timestamp to be automatically updated every time the record is updated (while not updating `Created_At`), you want :

```
UPDATE users SET Authenticated = 1, Created_At = Created_At WHERE ID = {$id};
```

3) As wisely commented by @Raymond Nijland, the best solution is to define the timestamp column to be autoupdated only on `UPDATE` operations, like :

```
`Authenticated_At` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: More simple would be to use `Authenticated_At datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   then Authenticated_At  automaticly updates when executing `UPDATE users SET Authenticated = 1 WHERE ID = {$id};` (keep in mind the SQL injection here)

Comment: @RaymondNijland : yes you are right, this is much more straightforward... I updated my answer. Thanks for checking on it !

Comment: "In order for the Authenticated_At timestamp to be automatically updated every time the record is updated (while not updating Created_At), you want :" Besides `UPDATE users SET Authenticated = 1, Created_At = Created_At WHERE ID = {$id};` should be more or less like `UPDATE users SET Authenticated = 1, Authenticated_At = NOW() WHERE ID = {$id};`

Comment: Thank you guys for answering. With your help I came up with the following solution:

    DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER update_authenticated_at 
        BEFORE UPDATE ON users
        FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                IF OLD.Authenticated <> NEW.Authenticated THEN
                SET NEW.Authenticated_At = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
            END IF;
        END //
DELIMITER ;

I tried using "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but than everytime I updated a column it would change Authenticated_At to current date. I needed It to update only when Autheticated became 1.

Comment: @RaymondNijland : updated again. So now we have 3 solutions, with the 3rd (yours) being the most relevant I believe.

Comment: "I needed It to update only when Autheticated became 1" @PietroBonfim then your trigger code might be wrong because it will also update Authenticated_At when Authenticated = 0 when Authenticated was 1 .. i think you meant using `IF (OLD.Authenticated <> NEW.Authenticated) AND (NEW.Authenticated = 1) THEN NEW.Authenticated_At = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ELSE NEW.Authenticated_At = NULL .. `

Comment: Oh, you are correct!!! I'll update the trigger! Technically it'd never be set back to 0, but what if it does. Thank you!